How to Increase the Maximum Number of Smart Card Readers Recognized by Windows 10 After Upgrading from Windows 7
At my workplace, we use multiple smart card readers connected to Windows 10 machines. However, our software seems to recognize only up to 10 smart card readers. This limitation wasn't present when we were using Windows 7; it started occurring after we upgraded to Windows 10.
I've noticed that the registry path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers might be related to this limitation.
Is there a way to bypass or increase the maximum number of smart card readers recognized by Windows 10? Has anyone encountered this issue during a Windows 7 to Windows 10 upgrade and found a solution?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Registry Exploration: I navigated to the registry path mentioned above to see if there's a configurable limit on the number of smart card readers. I expected to find a parameter or setting that I could modify to increase the limit beyond 10.
Driver Updates: I updated all smart card reader drivers to the latest versions, hoping that newer drivers would support more devices.
Device Manager Checks: In Device Manager, I looked for any hidden devices or errors that might indicate why additional readers aren't recognized.
Group Policy Settings: I reviewed local group policies related to smart card authentication to see if any settings could affect the number of recognized readers.
Testing on Different Machines: I connected the smart card readers to another Windows 10 machine to rule out hardware-specific issues.
Despite exploring the registry, I couldn't find any settings that would allow me to increase the limit.
Updating the drivers did not change the maximum number of recognized readers.
Device Manager doesn't show any issues; it simply doesn't list more than 10 smart card readers.
Group Policy settings didn't seem to have any relevant options to adjust this limit.
Testing on another Windows 10 machine resulted in the same limitation, suggesting it's an OS-level constraint.
